# How do Sports Illustrated's Gallery Pages Load So Fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I've been taking a look at their code and I can't quite figure it out.  Are they loading entire new pages, or are they using jquery to change the browser url and keep most of the page static?

[I'm viewing source of this page.](http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/multimedia/photo_gallery/0612/gallery.nba.big.season.trades/content.11.html)

Comment: the url is changing and it does not have a hash, so they are loading entire page, (maybe using cache

Comment: Are you referring to the "More Galleries" part at the bottom or the main content? The "More galleries" part is all preloaded. If you scroll down as soon as you open the page there is a bug that shows all of the preloaded images (I am on Chrome, browser execution may vary).

Comment: I'm referring to the current slideshow.  At the top of the right, the left and right pointing arrows next to 11 of 20

Comment: @Val - not true. For that they are using a new HTML 5 feature where you can overload the back and forward button. It changes the URL but I believe the content is preloaded, javascripted, or both. It appears here that when you press forward or back, it requests a new image and text content via JS.

Comment: @AndrewKS  html5 starts <!doctype> look at the source code and see if that changes ur mind

Comment: Vote this up if you were disapointed by the sports illustrated links and were expecting something different

Comment: You can use 'html5' features without using HTML5 syntax. Yet another fail in the marketing of HTML5 and new JS API's

Comment: @AndrewKS -- they aren't preloading it; using an HTTP debugger like Fiddler clearly shows the full content being loaded after the user clicks; however they may be using some HTML 5 features to quickly swap the new page for the old one with very little redraw time

Comment: Within the meta - canonical relations to the next page would help with caching?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "silver bullet" explanation--their site is likely fast because they've performance-tuned it and removed any significant bottlenecks.

They are in-fact reloading the page with each selected image--this is clear with a HTTP debugger such as Fiddler2.

The perceived speed is partly explained by their use of content-delivery-networks and gzip compression--both speed up delivery of content.  Their HTML structure likely factors is as well, and there is the chance they are streaming the response to allow the browser to begin rendering as early as possible.